# How to access events and helpers of a child-template in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

**There is an important edit at the end of this**.

## My Scenario:

```
<p>This is the parent template</p>
{{> childComponent }}
```

The `childComponent` consists of different UI-Elements allowing the user to **generate some input**. Think of the `childComponent` as a number-pad with a return-key `<a class="btn" id="submitStuff">Submit</a>` and some checkboxes.

The component is going to be used in different places in the app and each of the parent templates (using the component) make a different use of the `childComponent`'s output (the number and the information from the checkboxes). **The output is held as an `Object` in the Session**.

### What I need to do

When clicking the `#submitStuff` in the `childComponent` I want the childComponent's generated `Object` to be handled by a function in the wrapping parent-template.

### What I tried to do (and failed)

Of course I placed all the common behavior of `childComponent` in it's own template helpers and events. But because each parent template would make another / different use of the child's data (using the number for different purposes and interpreting the checkboxes in different ways), **I tried to listen to the submit-button in the `childComponent` from the parent's context**.

```
Template.parentTemplate.events({
    // trying to listen to the "#submitStuff"-button INSIDE the child-template
    // FAILS --> event is not visible to the outside of the child-component
    'click #submitStuff': function () {
        // get the information from the component
        // nothing happens
    }
});
```

This would be so easy. Just to place the `childComponent` anywhere and decide from the parent-context what to do with it's generated value. But it fails.

### Does anybody have a suggestion?

I thought about **using the Session**, but I am no fan of using the global space anytime I use the `childComponent`.

I thought about **defining a function in the parent** dealing with the submission and access that function from the `childComponent`. But I did not get it to work / don't know how to do it.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance!

## EDITs

**#1**

I was hinted to the most straight forward way and simply listen to the event in the parent-template-events. But as I wrote: "I tried to listen to the submit-button in the `childComponent` from the parent's context." It failed, the event never triggers anything in there (although it should!). When I listen to it **from INSIDE the `childComponent` itself**, everything is fine.

This is my setup:
http://meteorpad.com/pad/LWNKpfMCatSMhymhN/Copy%20of%20Parent-ChildTemplate

(It works as it should and as it does not in my project).

Does anybody know what could prevent an event from being caught in the parent template?

**#2**

I just figured out that it has something to do with a **plugin that I use: aldeed:template-extension**. After commenting out the line `Template.parentTemplate.replace('someBaseParent');`, it works as expected.

Yet I don't know if I just made a mistake in my way of using the plugin or if there is an issue with it.

Comment: Really hard to help without seeing any code other then you calling a template. But. It sounds like you want to create a method and have different places in your app use that method? If so, here's [Meteor's](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/security-with-methods) tutorial on it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal set of changes to the default meteor bootstrap code that shows you how an event in a parent template (Template.body in this case) can listen to events on elements defined in a child template (Template.hello), and access values from input elements contained in the child template.

test.html:

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <input type="number" id='num' value="">            // New input element
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
```

test.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });

  Template.body.events({                                     // event moved from Template.hello to parent Template.body
    'click button': function () {
      if (Template.instance().find('input').value === '') {  // get value from child template's input element
        // increment the counter when button is clicked                
        Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
      } else {
        Session.set('counter',
           Number(Template.instance().find('input').value)); // get value from child template's input element
        Template.instance().find('input').value = '';        // set value on child template's input element
      }
    },
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

[http://meteorpad.com/pad/mNjoRHdRk97cAyx7C/Parent-ChildTemplate](http://meteorpad%20example)

Comment: Your `hello` is my "childComponent". I tried to listen to the event `'click button'` (with the button being in the "childComponent") from the parent-template-helper, but the event `'click button'` triggers nothing. Only when I listen to the `'click button'` from INSIDE the childComponent... why is that? :-/

Comment: Here is the above working on meteorpad with the event on Template.body.  http://meteorpad.com/pad/mNjoRHdRk97cAyx7C/Parent-ChildTemplate

Comment: Oh my... this is exactly how I did it, because it was the most straight forward... but in fact: it does not work for me.
This is how I did it (it works in the pad but not in my project :'-( 
http://meteorpad.com/pad/LWNKpfMCatSMhymhN/Copy%20of%20Parent-ChildTemplate

The problem seems to be somewhere else. Do you know what could the event prevent from being cought in my parent template?

Comment: I think that the parent template event handlers are being attached to the dom when the parent template finishes rendering.  This is when child templates have already finished rendering, and any element selectors defined on the parent template will find the elements in the child templates and attach the event listeners to them.  However because you are inserting child templates (with `Template.parentTemplate.replace('someBaseParent');`) only the child template is being rendered, and only it's direct events will be attached.  The parent's events are not being attached to this new dom content.